# Kotlin EditText key listener only works in emulator

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a key listener on an editText element. The listener only fires in the emulator but not my device. Here is my onCreate:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val editText = EditText(this)
    mainLayout.addView(editText)

    editText.setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
        println("KEY PRESSED: " + keyCode)
        false
    })
}
```

How can I listen for key events on the device?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener):

> ...
>
> This is only useful for hardware keyboards; **a software input method
>   has no obligation to trigger this listener.**

So there's your answer. The AOSP/emulator keyboard happens to trigger it, but your keyboard doesn't.

Comment: @tmath I answered your question, at least how it's currently asked. You never actually states an intent, so I don't even know what you want to do.

Comment: Ok I updated the question. I want it to work on the device.

Comment: Like my answer says, what you're doing right now can't work. The only way to reliably listen to KeyEvents is through an accessibility service.